# Existence of "induced measure" on fibers of a measurable function between measure spaces?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, measurable-functions

Let $f : X\rightarrow Y$ be a measurable function between measure spaces $X,Y$ with measures denoted $\mu,\nu$ respectively. Suppose singleton subsets of $Y$ are measurable; hence fibers of $f$ are measurable subsets in $X$.

My question is, in general does there exist a collection $\{\lambda_y\}_{y\in Y}$ where $\lambda_y$ is a measure on $f^{-1}(y)$ for each $y\in Y$, such that for every measurable subset $A \subset X$ we have
$$
\mu(A) = \int_{y \in Y} \big(\lambda_y(A \cap f^{-1}(y))\big)\,d\nu(y)
\;\;?
$$

If not in general, then does this hold when, for example, $\mu,\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite and there is some kind of absolute continuity condition, as in the Radon-Nikodym theorem?

My guess would be that this is somehow related to the R-N theorem; however, I'm not sure how to construct any precise relationship between the two situations. Would anyone have any suggestions or hints on how to think about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, this decomposition exists if the measure spaces $X$ and $Y$ are [Lebesgue spaces](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lebesgue_space) and if $f$ sends $\mu$ to $\nu$.
The fibers of $f$ define a [measurable partition](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Measurable_decomposition) of $X$ on which we can decompose the measure $\mu$. This is called the [disintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem) of the measure with respect to the partition and goes back to a famous article of Rokhlin in the 40s.

The disintegration theorem is used in ergodic theory, for example, to define the ergodic decomposition of a probability measure invariant by some transformation of $X$: the measure can be written as an integral of ergodic measures defined on a partition of the space into invariant sets, known as the ergodic components of the system.